# Running Windows Form Application on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, user-interface, unix

I have built a Windows Form Application GUI on Microsoft Visual Studio. May I know what are the steps needed to run my application in Linux Environment? Thanks in advance!

Comment: google for the term mono. It is a replacement for the dotnet runtime that also runs on linux. Once installed you should be able to just run your application, have not tested it though

Comment: Another alternative to evaluate would be Wine

Answer (score 4):

Have you done some research about Mono? Few things that you need to know :

1. Mono is an Open source impementation of .NET for Linux
2. Mono is well documented and also supports LINQ, threading and most of the features of .NET.
3. It also lets you import dll files and use introp services.
4. First analyze your code using MoMA (Mono Migration Analyzer)---

   http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/moma

Warning: 
  LINUX uses "/" as directory separator while Windows uses "\".

More info :

http://www.mono-project.com/

Comment: Mono doesn’t support WinForms, because it’s tied into the Windows OS. You’d need to rewrite the UI with a platform available library, like GTK# https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/